# How I can Merge two pdf pages into one page using Zendframework

Tags: magento2, php, zend-framework, php-7.4, zend

I'm trying to merge two pdf pages one is packing slips and another one is shipment labels, I can merge the two pdf by creating another page but I want to merge the two pages into a single page and 2nd page should be rendered in the landscape.